# Why console logs is being printed after fetch prmise and this.setState just right when I click the button

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I have a touchableOpacity area with an image inside it. I want to make when a user click the image, set de opacity of touchableOpacity to 0.2, then execute a fetch which will get 0 or 1 as result. If 0, change image to black and white, otherwise color image. But I cound't get that far. Can't find the reason why when I click the touchableOpacity area, console.log prints in the console its value, but not set the state.opacity.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image, TouchableOpacity, View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import styles from './Estilos';

export default class LightsContainer extends Component {
constructor() {
super();

  this.state = { opacity: 0.9 };
}

onPress = () => {

    fetch("http://192.168.0.161/switch.php?port=1")
        .then(response => response.text()) 
        .then((dataStr) => {

        console.log(dataStr);     

        if (dataStr == 1){

            this.setState({opacity: 0.9});
            console.log("si");

        } else {

            this.setState({opacity: 0.2});
            console.log("no");

        }
    });     

    console.log(this.state);
}

render() {
return (
 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'steelblue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}  >
        <TouchableOpacity style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} >
            <Image source={require('./bulb-512.png')}  style={{width: 150, height: 150, top:-40}} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}  >
            <Image source={require('./bulb-512.png')}  style={{width: 150, height: 150, top:-10}} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}  >
            <Image source={require('./bulb-512.png')}  style={{width: 150, height: 150, top:20}} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console log will all happen almost immediately since JavaScript is a synchronous language.

Before the fetch is returned (while the data is still incoming), the `console.log(this.state)` will already happen, so the last line of `onPress` will log the initial state. Keep in mind as well that [React's setState method itself is asynchronous!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3), so the logs for `si` and `no` might not occur after `setState` has completed.

To remedy this, you may want to look into [async/await syntax](https://javascript.info/async-await), which will let your async code run 'synchronously', by waiting for the Promises to resolve